# get message without re open div

Tags: javascript

Im working in a chat system very simple. But i have a problem. I can only get the other user messages if i close and re open the chat conversation div, then the message appears.

How can I solve this? The problem should be in this piece of code. As I am not very comfortable with ajax I ask for your help.

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var snd = new Audio("images/new_msg.wav"); 
var open=Array();




$("#jd-chat .jd-online_user").click(function(){
    var user_name = $.trim($(this).text());
    var id = $.trim($(this).attr("id"));

    if($.inArray(id,open) !== -1 )
        return

    open.push(id);

    $("#jd-chat").prepend('<div class="jd-user">\
        <div class="jd-header" id="' + id + '">' + user_name + '<span class="close-this"> X </span></div>\
        <div class="jd-body"></div>\
        <div class="jd-footer"><input id="textareabox" placeholder="escrever..."></div>\
    </div>');
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat.class.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'get_all_msg=true&user=' + id ,
        success:function(data){
            $("#jd-chat").find(".jd-user:first .jd-body").append("<span style='display:block' class='me'> " + data + "</span>");

        }
    });
});
$("#jd-chat").delegate(".close-this","click",function(){
    removeItem = $(this).parents(".jd-header").attr("id");
    $(this).parents(".jd-user").remove();

    open = $.grep(open, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    }); 
});

$("#jd-chat").delegate(".jd-header","click",function(){
    var box=$(this).parents(".jd-user,.jd-online");
    $(box).find(".jd-body,.jd-footer").slideToggle();
});

$("#search_chat").keyup(function(){
    var val =  $.trim($(this).val());
    $(".jd-online .jd-body").find("span").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, "i")) < 0 ) 
        {
            $(this).fadeOut(); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).show();              
        }
    });
});

$("#jd-chat").delegate(".jd-user input","keyup",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 )
    {
        var $cont = $('.jd-body');

        var box=$(this).parents(".jd-user");
        var msg=$(box).find("input").val();
        var to = $.trim($(box).find(".jd-header").attr("id"));

        $.ajax({
            url:'chat.class.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'send=true&to=' + to + '&msg=' + msg,
            success:function(data){ 
            $('#textareabox').val('');
            $(box).find(".jd-body").append("<span style='display:block'  class='me'> " + msg + "</span>");



            $cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;
            $cont.append('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
            $cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;
            $(this).val('');


            }
        });
    }
});










function message_cycle()
{   
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat.class.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'unread=true',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){             
            $.each(data , function( index, obj ) {
                var user = index;                   
                var box  = $("#jd-chat").find("div#2").parents(".jd-user");

                $(".jd-online").find(".light").hide();

                $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
                    if($.inArray(user,open) !== -1 )                                            
                        $(box).find(".jd-body").append("<span style='display:block'  class='other'> " + value + "</span>");                     
                    else            
                        snd.play();
                        $(".jd-online").find("span#" + user + " .light").show();        


                });
            });             
        }
    });
}

setInterval(message_cycle,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How messages are displayed when you first open the chat conv div ?

I'm assuming message_cycle() is supposed to display new messages in your div every second, i suppose your problem is here...

I'm not really confortable with this :

`var box  = $("#jd-chat").find("div#2").parents(".jd-user");`

A div can't have an id starting with a number, you need `<div id="chat2">` instead of `<div id="2">`.

After your line add a `console.log('Box found : '+box.length) ;` just to make sure your box is correctly found in message_cycle.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. I made these changes and still the same

Comment: yap, is that the problem. The div ID need to be the user ID. I tested in debug mode, and if the user header id was = "2" so i get the messages. how can do that? like this `var box  = $("#jd-chat").find("div#'+id+' ").parents(".jd-user");`

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your question : `var box = $("#jd-chat").find("div#'+id+' ").parents(".jd-user");` looks correct to me : are you asking how to retreive the id ? it's not the `var = user ?`

Comment: yes, i fixed that div id. now div id = user id, looks correct to me too. but the problem its the same.